# Loop in proc sql select

Tags: sas

I need to break one vaiable into multiple variables (max length 2000).
For example my **string** has length 10000000 (10 mb) I use:

```
proc sql;
create table str as 
    select
    substr(string,2000,1) as field1,
    substr(string,2000,2001) as field2,
    .......
from data_table
```

Could I write loop in select statement not to write these field1-field5000.
Thank you!

Comment: What is source of this long string? Is it database table?

Comment: @fl0r3k Yes its data table but I need to use only proc sql, not data step

Comment: where exacly this table is residing? I database like mysql or oracle?

Comment: Why the max length of 2000?  SAS allows you to store strings up to 32767 characters long.

Comment: If you bring it to a data step this is a bit easier. Is your entire table the string that's 10MB?

Comment: @RobertPenridge  I am working with dbms object

Answer (score 1):

**First**

`substr()` function takes 3 arguments

```
substr(string, position <, length>)

    string - string constatn or field
    position - starting position
    length - length of the string you want to return
```

**Second**

In `proc sql` you can only use macro language loops so you must write macroprogram.

```
options mprint;

%macro substrLoop;
%let length = 2000;
%let endLoop = %eval(1000000/&length.);

proc sql;
   create table str as 
      select
      %do i = 1 %to &endLoop.;
         substr(string, %eval(1 + (&i.-1)*&length.),&length.) as field&i.
         %if &i ne &endLoop. %then ,;
      %end;
   from data_table;
quit;
%mend substrLoop;

%substrLoop
```

Explanation

`options mprint;`

enables to see in log code that was generated by called macro

`%let length = 2000;`

`%let endLoop = %eval(1000000/&length.);`

Setting macarovariables for length of substring and calculating when loop should end.

```
%do i = 1 %to &endLoop.;
   substr(string, %eval(1 + (&i.-1)*&length.),&length.) as field&i.
   %if &i ne &endLoop. %then ,;
%end;
```

Actual loop puting `substr(string, 1,2000) as field1 ,`  `substr(string, 2001,2000) as field2 ,` etc. calculated fields into sql code.

`%if &i ne &endLoop. %then ,;` is needed to prevent puting comma after last generated field.

Comment: thanks, now I have ERROR: Out of memory. Try reducing READBUFF/INSERTBUFF/UPDATEBUFF option value. Do you know how can I prevent it?

Comment: Those options are engine specific.
1. How do you assign library you are reding from? Is it done by administrator or you write your own `LIBNAME`?
2. Do you want results to be stored in oracle?